# How to set dropdown list value using laravel and ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am using laravel and ajax. I have a function like this below for the ajax. I it shows the list for the drop-down field, but I cannot set the list selected from the data that I have already saved in the database. This is for the update form.

```
public function getTugasDetailUpdate(Request $request)
{   
    $update_tugas_id = $request->get("V_ID_PK");
    $getDataListPengikut = DB::select("EXEC dbo.GET_KEMENPAR_LIST_PENGIKUT '".$update_tugas_id."'");
    $getPengikut2 = DB::select("EXEC dbo.LOV_M_PENGIKUT");
    $msg["opt"] ="";
    $no=1;
    foreach($getDataListPengikut as $dtListPengikut):
        $msg["opt"] .= '<tr>
            <td><select class="form-control" id="name_'.$dtListPengikut->KODE.'" name="nameupdate[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
                <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>'; 
                    foreach ($getPengikut2 as $getPeng){
                      $msg["opt"] .=   '<option value="'.$getPeng->KODE.'"@if( '.$dtListPengikut->DESKRIPSI.'=='.$getPeng->KODE.') selected @endif>'. $getPeng->DESKRIPSI .'</option>'; 
                    } 
                $msg["opt"] .='</select>
            </td> 
            if ($no == 1){   
            $msg["opt"] .=   '<td><button type="button" name="add" id="addupdate'.$no.'" onclick="addMe(this);return false" class="btn btn-success"><b>+</b></button>
                </td>';
            }
            else{
                $msg["opt"] .=   '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="removeupdate'.$no.'" onclick="removeMe(this);return false" class="btn btn-danger"><b>x</b></button>
                </td>';
            }
            $msg["opt"] .=  '</tr>';
            $no++;
            endforeach;
       echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

If I do an inspect an element, it is shows like this:
[image]

Comment: This is simple php output, why you use blade tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your foreach as below. You have issue with string concatination

```
foreach ($getPengikut2 as $getPeng){
    $selected = "";
    if($dtListPengikut->DESKRIPSI == $getPeng->KODE)
        $selected = "selected";
      $msg["opt"] .=   '<option value="'.$getPeng->KODE.'"'. $selected.'>'. $getPeng->DESKRIPSI .'</option>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you use plain html output, there's no need to use blade tags:

```
$msg["opt"] .= '<option value="' . $getPeng->KODE . '"'
    . ($dtListPengikut->DESKRIPSI == $getPeng->KODE ? ' selected' : '')
    . '>' . $getPeng->DESKRIPSI .'</option>';
```